How to remove smart card certificates (use “certutil”) in 2024?
I am trying to use a script to remove smart card certificates in the personal certificate store. I am aware of how to do this manually through internet options however I would like to use a script to remove the certificates from the store automatically on logoff (I know how to run logoff scripts).
I found an answer from Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007, and this script works, but not for all current and newer certificates from 2024 (this post is from 2015). I have attempted to understand how these certs work but it eludes me.
How can this script from Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 be modified to make this script work with newer certificates?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

There isn’t an answer by Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 to that particular question. The only real answer has a single command and see no reason why the command would have stopped removing smart card certificates in 2024.

What kind of certificates, exactly? This looks like it's not a "2024" problem, but rather a "command assumes a specific kind of certificate" problem – the '1.3.6.1.4.1.311.20.2.2' filters for ones issued according to the MS Smartcard Logon template; is that what your smartcards have, or do they have some other shape of certificate?

Is this a shared computer or a shared Windows account? So are you trying to remove traces that you'd ever used that account or something? Because if this is your own account on your own machine, there's no security risk in leaving a certificate in your cert store. Certs only contain public keys. The private key stays locked in your smartcard.

So over time, new certificates have been added and existing ones have been modified on smart cards. When inserting a smart card, 4 certificates populate in the personal store. When executing the script by Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 only 2 of them are removed on current cards - previously all certificates were removed.
This script is intended to be ran in a computer lab where many users insert their cards daily.

Those 2 smartcards must have a different (extended) key usage identifier. Look up which it is and add a second line deleting those. The EKU is probably 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.2 for the other smart cards, but look it up to be sure.
